# How to retrieve objects from the sotlayer saved quote using Python API

Tags: python, rest, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to retrieve the objects/items (server name, host name, domain name, location, etc...) that are stored under the saved quote for a particular Softlayer account. Can someone help how to retrieve the objects within a quote? I could find a REST API (Python) to retrieve quote details (quote ID, status, etc..) but couldn't find a way to fetch objects within a quote.

Thanks!

Best regards,

Khelan Patel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to retrieve the same order information structure you sent when placing the quote then you need to use the method [getRecalculatedOrderContainer](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/getRecalculatedOrderContainer/), it should returns the packageId, presetId, location, item prices, etc., but as far as I know, the hostname, domain, sshKeys, provisionScripts, vlans aren't in the quote since those values 
could change over the time whether the user requires new values before placing the order or to avoid errors from system due to availability of resources like vlans and subnets.

```
https://[username]:[apikey]api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/[quoteID]/getRecalculatedOrderContainer
Method: GET
```

Now if you want to retrieve orderId, items, etc, then you need to use [object-mask](https://softlayer.github.io/article/object-masks/) feature whether you are using the methods `Account::getQuotes` or `SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote::getObject` they both returns the datatype [SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/) in a list or as a single object.

**Account::getQuotes**

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getQuotes?objectMask=mask[id,name,order[id,status,items[id,description,domainName,hostName,location]]]

Method: GET
```

**SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote::getObject**

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/[quoteID]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,name,order[id,status,items[id,description,location]]]

Method: GET
```

References:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getQuotes/

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Albert getRecalculatedOrderContainer is the thing I was looking for.

Comment: You can also review this https://softlayer.github.io/python/order_quote_advanced/, there is information about how to work with quotes